# Sorting non ascii characters in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting, non-ascii-characters

Users submitted those weird characters. How to sort them along with normal text in Dart ?

```
ℝ
```

The good old
`b.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(a.name.toLowerCase());` does not work

Comment: in other words how to translate them to iciala Fakncra mleClara Hrie ...

Comment: .toLowerCase says "This function uses the language independent Unicode mapping and thus only works in some languages."  I don't think there's any better way of doing it, unless you have magical knowledge about the Unicode characters involved.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Just found https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic, which appears as though it might do roughly what you want, although I'm not sure of how many different characters it supports.

---

Well, a good place to start might be looking at the internal implementation of the ES6 [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) function.

Interestingly, it only works in Compatibility Decomposition mode - ie. NFKC or NFKD.

```js
for (const weirdString of [
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  'ℝ',
]) {console.log(weirdString.normalize('NFKC'))}
```

---

Anyway, maybe there is a translation in Dart, or you can use the 'dart:js' library if you're running on the web, or you could find the implementation in the V8 engine (although it'll probably be in C).